# Does there exist $y$ so that $\int \sum_{i =1}^N f_i(x) g_i(x)=\sum_{i=1}^N f_i(y) \int g_i(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f_i,g_i: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$, where $i=1, \ldots, N$, be continuous functions. Does there exist $y \in [0,1]$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^N f_i(y) \int_0^1 g_i(x) dx= \sum_{i=1}^N \int_0^1 f_i(x) g_i(x) dx?$$
The answer is yes for $N=1$, but the proof doesn't seem to easily translate for $N>1$. If the answer is no can you find a counterexample?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since posting I've realised that the answer is no. Consider the functions $f_1=g_1=\chi_{[0,1/4]}$ and $f_2=g_2=\chi_{[1/2,3/4]}$, where $\chi$ is the indicator function (the idea can be adapted to make the functions continuous). Then $\sum \int f_i(x) g_i(x) dx =1/2$, but for all $y \in [0,1]$, $\sum f_i(y) \int g_i(x) dx= 1/4 \sum f_i(y) \leq 1/4$.